# Dropwizard Rest Application. How to view only my custom metrics

Tags: rest, customization, metrics, dropwizard, health-check

Hello Rest Api lovers !!

I created a DropWizard basic rest application.
I would like to view metrics but ONLY MY CUSTOM ONES and not dropwizard api's.
how can i disable dropwizard's healtCheks and Metrics and only view mines (the custum ones).
I hope it is clear....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are concerned about the "view" part of metrics/healthchecks, you can set filter that will apply when data is returned. It can be done on start of an application:

```java
environment.getAdminContext().setAttribute(MetricsServlet.METRIC_FILTER, new MetricFilter() {
   @Override
   public boolean matches(final String name, final Metric metric) {
       return // you logic;
   }
});
environment.getAdminContext().setAttribute(HealthCheckServlet.HEALTH_CHECK_FILTER, new HealthCheckFilter() {
   @Override
   public boolean matches(final String s, final HealthCheck healthCheck) {
       return // you logic;
   }
});
```

2. If you don't want to have metrics/healthchecks at all, you can directly remove them:

```java
environment.healthChecks().unregister();
environment.metrics().remove();
```